# Why doesn't user notification delegate work?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, notifications, swift3

I'm setting up an app that will use user notifications. I already have one app working. I do the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

This produces the following compiler error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate?'
```

What's strange is in the other app, I do the exactly same thing and it works fine. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Does ViewController conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate ?

Comment: ah - that's the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your class to implement the protocol **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**.  Note that all of the methods in this protocol are optional so actually the code with the empty implementation below is sufficient to compile, but you probably want to implement at least one of them to do anything meaningful with the notitification.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    }
```